# How can I make docker-compose pull images using a socks5 proxy?

Tags: proxy, docker, socks

I'm trying to pull images through a socks5 proxy. I've started the socks5 proxy on port `8888` like this:

```
ssh -NC -D 8888 parham@***.***.**
```

However, when I run `docker-compose` like this, it is evident that it's not using the environment variable:

```
$ ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:8888 docker-compose up
```

How can I make Docker pull images through this proxy?

Comment: docker-compose doesn't pull images. It tells Docker to pull the images.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like this feature has been [recently](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/20366) added to `docker`, particularly in version `1.11.0`. 
Though there isn't enough documentation about its usage, setting the `ALL_PROXY` environment variable should work, according to [this comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23931#issuecomment-233035772).

```
$ export ALL_PROXY=socks5://localhost:port 
$ docker pull image
```

I'm not sure about `docker-compose` at the moment.
If your primary aim is to speed up the download process using socks5, you might be able to achieve the purpose by manually pulling images using `docker pull` before finally running `docker-compose up`.

Comment: It works for `docker-compose` too. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

### Method 1

Error:

```
docker-compose up 
Pulling web (jitsi/web:stable-6433)...
ERROR: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
```

then setting `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` this way:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=socks5://localhost:9040/
export HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://localhost:9040/
```

result:

```
docker-compose up 
Pulling web (jitsi/web:stable-6433)...
stable-6433: Pulling from jitsi/web
b380bbd43752: Downloading [===================>                               ]  10.36MB/27.14MB
0312863d422f: Download complete
503063a74a58: Downloading [============================>                      ]  7.998MB/14.15MB
392a862abfe3: Download complete
41a073b705ed: Download complete
a8f4844f6941: Download complete
f500f1f2f4ae: Downloading [============>                                      ]  11.69MB/47.56MB
```

A shot of before `HTTP_PROXY` and after setting them up:

[image]

### Method 2

If method 1 did not work (simple one) you can go with [this one](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/):

#### first

Find systemd location for configuration:

```
systemctl status docker | grep docker.service\;
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
```

which here for my on Debian 9 is `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` and its directory is `/lib/systemd/system/`
So `cd` into `/lib/systemd/system/`.

#### second

`mkdir` for `docker.service.d` or:

```
mkdir docker.service.d && cd !$
```

#### third

In `docker.service.d` directory create a `.conf` file like: **http-proxy.conf**

#### forth

Add these in **http-proxy.conf** file:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=socks5://localhost:9040"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://localhost:9040"
```

NOTE that `localhost:9040` is mine, update it if you have a different IP or PORT

#### fifth

Because we update the configuration run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and then restart docker service

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Now it is up and running:

[image]

Comment: if your version of docker is 3+ years old, step one might be to upgrade ... none of this worked till I upgraded.

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction - you are welcome if the answer needs an update and I appreciate it

Comment: I tried the steps under **Method 2** on two Ubuntu servers ( 20.04 and 22.04 ) and the steps listed under **Method 2** appear to work flawlessly. On Ubuntu you'll need to create `docker.service.d/` under `/etc/systemd/system/`. I.e. you'll need `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`  to contain the proxy directives ( Many thanks by the way! ).

Answer (score 1):

@nikhilweee's answer above is missing a crucial point.

The proxy used for image-pull is taken from the environment of `dockerd`. There is presently no way to change it without restarting `dockerd`.

I have filed [moby issue #37335](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37335) about it, because I wanted to use a specific proxy for a single pull command, but not in general.

Answer (score 0):

In Docker 17.07 and higher, you can also use `json` file for proxy configuration:

```sh
       $ vim ~/.docker/config.json

          {
            "proxies":
              {
                "default":
                 {
                  "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8118",
                  "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8118"
                  }
              }
          }

        $  docker pull ubuntu:18.04
        $  docker-compose build
```

[More](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client) info in official docs.

And in addition to use `Socks`, You can forward `Socks` to  `HTTP`  by using `privoxy`:

```sh
    $ sudo apt install -y privoxy
    $ sudo vim /etc/privoxy/config
    
              forward-socks5 / 127.0.0.1:9090  .
              forward-socks4a / 127.0.0.1:9090 .
              forward-socks5t             /     127.0.0.1:9090 .
              forward         192.168.*.*/     .
              forward            10.*.*.*/     .
              forward           127.*.*.*/     .
              forward           localhost/     .
    
    $ sudo service privoxy restart
```

[More](https://neoctobers.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/latest/rpi/socks_to_http.html) info in official docs.